# Laravel Auth non-object after logout. Middleware running in wrong order?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.6, I have a middleware that generates my user menus. Within this middleware I have a route which goes to the account edit page;

```
action("CompanyController@edit", ['company' => Auth::user()->company->id])
```

If the user logs out the following error is thrown on logout:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'company' of non-object
```

I can get around this by changing the route to:

```
action("CompanyController@edit", ['company' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->company->id : ''])
```

Now an unauthenticated user results in a re-direct to the login page and no errors thrown - as expected.

However this does not feel right. Should the auth middleware not catch this before anything else is executed? Is there any way to get around having to complete the auth check before trying to get user details back?

Comment: That does sound a bit off.  Your action() call is in a blade template? ... And you use that helper instead of routes files?  Correct?

Comment: Where did you applied the Middleware? Put the related code.

Comment: Probably the controller ... so they'll want to stop using action() and instead keep route files and call named route()'s

Comment: Does using an action vs route have different effects? I thought the route would directly control the action assigned to it? My action has a route so I can use either.